# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" while connecting to Hive using Jdbc

Tags: java, hive

I am trying to connect to hive using `jdbc` program found [here](https://gist.github.com/sdpatil/bd0fc7ec639a08e0f48f):

```
package com.hive;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class HiveJdbcClient
{
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main( String[] args )throws Exception{
    try {

        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection connection = null;
            System.out.println("Before getting connection");
            connection=  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://10.25.3.208:10000/default", "hive", "");
            System.out.println("After getting connection " + connection);

            ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from default.tstest");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

}

I changed the `hive2` to `hive` and changed the driver name from `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` to `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`.

Now I get the following error:

```
Before getting connection
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have the following `jars` in my classpath:

```
hive-common-0.8.1  
hive-metastore-0.8.1  
hive-service-0.8.1  
httpclient-4.3.3  
httpcore-4.2.1  
httpmime-4.3  
libfb303-0.9.0  
libthrift-0.9.0  
hive-exec-0.8.1  
hive-jdbc-0.10.0  
slf4j.api-1.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a SLF4J implementation as well in the classpath. There are several options depending on the logging system you want to use. The chosen logging system itself must be added as well unless it is built into the JRE.

An easy approach is to add `slf4j-simple` if you don't need advanced logging features.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/docs.html) for more details.

Comment: I added slf4j-simple-1.6.1 jar to the classpath , now there is no error but the program is getting stuck .

Comment: That's another problem that probably deserves its own question. Do you see some output of the program?

Comment: Only this is getting displayed:  Before getting connection

Comment: Ok, seems like nothing is answering at this address. Network or firewall issue? If you wait long enough, do you get a timeout exception?

Comment: I am not getting any exception